# Does the yolk sac for Danio rerio form at the vegetal pole?

Tags: ichthyology, embryology

Does the yolk sac in general form always at the vegetal pole?
If so, is this the case for [*Danio rerio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebrafish) (the zebrafish)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, yes, yolk is at the vegetal pole. There may be exceptions but I am not aware of them.

You can read about zebrafish (Danio rerio) embryology in great detail in [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/aja.1002030302). Figure 3 from this paper (see image) shows the immediate post-fertilization zygote, in which the animal-vegetal axis is first set up by the migration of non-yolk to the animal pole.

[image: figure3]

UPDATE: very explicitly labeled yolk figures.

[image: yolk poles]
[image: yolk embryos]

Comment: Thank you! I read a paper but it was not clear to me where the yolk sac was eaxctly.

Comment: See new figures from paper in update.